# Why does recursive function for travelling to front of doubly linked list not work?

Tags: python, data-structures, recursion

I am a novice who has just finished edX's introductory course MIT 6.00.1x; the following is related to a problem on that course's final exam (now concluded, so I can seek help).  Let

```
def class DLLNode(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.cargo = cargo
        self.before = None
        self.after = None
    def setBefore(self, before):  self.before = before
    def setAfter(self, after):    self.after = after
    def getBefore(self):          return self.before
    def getAfter(self):           return self.after
    def getCargo(self):           return self.cargo
```

be used to create a doubly linked list.  Suppose `node` is an instance of class `DLLNode` that appears in a doubly linked list.  Then `node.getBefore()` returns that `node`'s immediate predecessor in the list, except that it returns `None` if `node` is at the front of the list and so has no predecessor.

I have written a *recursive* function

```
def firstInList(nodeInList):
    """ Prints out the cargo carried by the first node in that doubly linked list
    of which nodeInList is a part.  Returns that first node. """

    if nodeInList.getBefore() == None:
        firstnode = nodeInList
        print firstnode.getCargo()
        return firstnode
    # nodeInList.getBefore() is not None, so nodeInList has an immediate predecessor 
    # on which firstInList can be be called.
    firstInList(nodeInList.getBefore())
```

that I wish to return the first node in a doubly linked list, given as argument a known node `nodeInList` in the list.

**My problem:**  `firstInList` arrives at the correct first node, as evidenced by its printing the first node's cargo regardless of the specific `nodeInList` used.  But whenever `nodeInList` is *not* the first node in the linked list, the return value of `firstInList(node)` turns out to be `None` rather than the desired first node.  This conclusion is based on the following:  If, for example, the list's first node `node1` has cargo `1` and is followed by `node2` with cargo `2`, then `firstInList(node2) == None` evaluates as `True` but `firstInList(node2) == node1` evaluates as `False`.  A call `firstInList(node2).getCargo()` will return an error message

> Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getCargo'

Another datum is that `firstInList(node1) == node1` evaluates as `True`; that, at least, is as I would expect.

This suggests the `firstnode` found is not being returned back up the chain of recursive calls in the way I have imagined.  *Can anyone explain why?*

(Please do not suggest that I use iteration instead of recursion.  I know how to do that.  I am trying to understand Python 2.7's behavior for the code as written.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reason for return statement in recursive function call](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/201765/reason-for-return-statement-in-recursive-function-call)

Answer (score 3):

Well, it would appear that you're not `return`ing the result of the recursion, so the function will in all cases but the degenerate simply return the default uninitialized value.

The last line should be:

```
return firstInList(nodeInList.getBefore())
```

Comment: Your answer is something I'd considered, but it doesn't really answer the question asked.  Arriving at the list's `firstnode` is the base case of the recursion, and the function _does_ arrive at that base case, as evidenced by the printing out of the correct value of  `firstnode.cargo`.  So _why_ doesn't a simple `return firstnode` instruction suffice?

Comment: @GregGrunberg Because `return` returns only from the current function call (stack frame). If you do not use the returned value then it will be discarded. But function that called it **has to** return something. If you do not explicitly say what, it will just return some value depending on the language(platform). It returns `None` in python, it returns some garbage in C\C++, or it just won't compile in a language with stricter rules. You can also read the following article - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/201765/reason-for-return-statement-in-recursive-function-call.

Comment: Please add the change in code, for future reference, as your answer is correct but doesn't illustrate how to solve it

Comment: @holroy: I see I forgot to let you know that I did that!

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Nathan Tuggy.  At first I misunderstood what you were saying, but in fact you were correct.

My `firstInList` function worked perfectly once I changed the last line

> `firstInList(nodeInList.getBefore())`

to read

> `return firstInList(nodeInList.getBefore())`  .

Given the ridiculous number of hours I've spent worrying about this, I think this is a type of mistake I'm not likely to make in the future.  Or if I do, I'll be able to discover the problem myself.